# How the record assign in queue?

Tags: case, assignment-rules, queue

Queues help your teams manage leads, cases, service contracts, and custom objects. Once records are placed in a queue manually or through an automatic case or lead assignment rule, **records remain there until they're assigned to a user or taken by one of the queue members.** Any queue member or users above them in the role hierarchy can take ownership of records in a queue.

I have doubt in statement **"records remain there until they're assigned to a user or taken by one of the queue members"**,

> When a record is reaches to the queue , it will allocate the record to only one user in the queue or all the member of queue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you assign record to QUEUE any Queue member can take ownership of the record. It will allocate to only one user in the queue.

All users have options to take the ownership but only one user can take ownership at a time. So in case if any user is on leave then other user can handle that case.

You also have option to send notification email to Queue user whenever a new Case assign to that queue.

You can use Case Assignment rule to easily assign case to different queue based on some criteria.

Comment: In case there are 5 A,B,C,D,E user in IT_Team Queue, An record is assigned to an IT_Team Queue,.  And case is assigned one user (A) in that. Whether other remaining 4(B,C,D,E) user  can see the record after allocating first user(A) in that queue ?

Comment: @NITHESHK Unless they have permission they can't.